# python.exe - System Error

Tags: python, installation

I recently attempted to install Python 3.6.0 but at the end of the installation this pop up box appeared:

[image]

Here is the exact text of the pop-up box:

> python.exe - System Error
>
> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

I have already reinstalled Python 3.6 twice and the error hasn't disappeared, so it must not be talking about reinstalling Python. Does anyone know what this error is and how to fix this? If you do then it would really help.

Comment: When you get enough reputation, use images only when required and include the text from the image just like you did now.

Comment: I googled and found this: https://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/the-program-cant-start-because-api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0dll-is-missing-f2702.html

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for your version of Windows (x64)

For Windows x64:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x64.exe

For Windows x86:
http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/F/93FCF1E7-E6A4-478B-96E7-D4B285925B00/vc_redist.x86.exe